# Printing from a mobile with Firefox OS

Tags: printing, firefox-os

Is it possible - and if so, how? - to print from a Firefox OS phone?

Looking for a real mobile solution - e.g., printing out a receipt using mobile phone and a small receipt printer (connected probably through usb or wifi tethering) at a marketplace, on a train, etc. (The mobile will communicate through internet with a server, so it will have an internet connection.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the printer on the same network as the Firefox OS device then you could try running this pure JavaScript implementation of the [Internet Printing Protocol](https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp) to send a file to the printer from your app. It would definitely need some changes to use standard web APIs rather than Node JS APIs. It may be possible to implement it with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or perhaps something lower level like [TCPSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket).

Comment: This is the low level [printWindow](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/printing/content/printUtils.js#104-111) function but I don't know of a way to access this from Firefox OS.